# How to access a nested static class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to nest a static class within another one, for tidy access when using the styles later. Desired result is to be able to access it like this:

```
OverviewTheme.text.boxName
```

However, I'm getting a `'boxName' not defined` error upon trying the above.
How do I do it properly?

Please see the code:

```
class OverviewTheme {
  static const Color secondaryColor = Color(0xFFFFFF00);
  static const Color primaryColor = Color(0xFFFFFFFF);
  static const Color backgroundColor = Color(0xFF555555);
  static const _TextStyles text = _TextStyles();
}

class _TextStyles {
  const _TextStyles();
  static const TextStyle boxName =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 11, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold);
  static const TextStyle boxDescription = TextStyle(fontSize: 10);
  static const TextStyle boxNumber =
      TextStyle(fontSize: 10, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Static members of a particular class are accessed at the class level, not the object level. So, you can't access boxName.

Comment: So the only way to do this is to ditch the static and instantiate the class instead?

Comment: Yes you need to remove static